# Extend background image on block beyond container with css

Tags: css, wordpress

WordPress, Neve, unable to override the full-width on a cover image. I would like to extend the cover image beyond the container, and unable to figure out an easy fix. The site I'm working on is   https://cheapsafetysigns.com/testing/about/. It's the banner at the top that I'm having the issue with. You can see that I'm managed to extend the backgrounds on the other covers, but haven't figured out the image bleed.

I had the same issue for the other covers with a simple background thanks to this forum, but I have a cover where the image won't extend edge-to-edge. Any ideas?

I used the following css for the bg colour and it worked a treat:

```
    .full-bleed-dark {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax #202527;
      clip-path: inset(0 -100vmax); 
    }
```

I'm hoping for a similar simple fix to css for the image to do the same. I've tried changing the template used for the page, but then I don't have the content contained and I still want it to have a boxed layout.